# R - Function That Returns Default Value - getOrElse

Tags: r

I am trying to create a function that will evaluate an expression and if the result of that expression is not "finite" (defined by is.finite) then it will return a default value.  The function should still return the default value in case of a thrown error.  The function should also be vectorized.

This should be silly-easy, but I just don't fully understand R's error trapping functionality.  Can someone help improve/simplify this function to meet these test cases?

Here is the start of a function that I have.  Even if it would work, its rather ugly.

```
getOrElse <- function (expr, default = 0) {

    # protect against any errors
    val <- tryCatch (expr, error = function (e) {})

    # replace any non-finite values
    val [!is.finite(val)] <- default

    # this is really ugly
    if (length(val) > 1 && !is.finite(val)) val <- default

    return (val)
}
```

And here are the "test cases"...

```
getOrElse (sqrt(4), default = 10) == 2 # WORKS

getOrElse (stop ("ignore"), default = 10) == 10  # BROKEN

getOrElse (sqrt(c(4, 16, NA, NaN)), default = 0) == c(2, 4, 0, 0) # BROKEN

getOrElse (sqrt(c(4, 16)), default = 0) == c(2, 4)  # WORKS

getOrElse (c(NA, NA), default = 10) == c(10, 10)  # WORKS
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not really doing anything when you get an error, so consider this modification:

```
getOrElse <- function (expr, default = 0) {
    stopifnot(length(default) == 1)
    val <- tryCatch (expr, error = function (e) {})
    if( length(val) ){
         val [!is.finite(val)] <- default
      } else { 
         val <- default}

    return (val)
}
```

It still will fail your test with `getOrElse (sqrt(c(4, 16, NA, Nan)), default = 0) == c(2, 4, 0, 0)` but that is because `Nan` is not `NaN` and the code above would return a length 1 with the 'default' value. If you used instead a test with `getOrElse (sqrt(c(4, 16, NA, NaN)), default = 0) == c(2, 4, 0, 0)` it would succeed. If you still require that you return the function in the expression applied separately to each of the arguments to the function, then you will need to do more complex deparsing.

Comment: I fixed the typo on Nan... Should have been NaN.

Comment: Then I think you have your answer.

Comment: Yep, I sure do.  I appreciate the help.

Comment: Why not do `val <- tryCatch (expr, error = function (e) default)` ?  Then you don't need the if statement because value will always have length > 0.

Comment: I'd probably also add `stopifnot(length(default) == 1)`

Comment: The return of 'default' from inside the `error`-function is quite elegant.